# Update Mongo collection fields with values from other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm refactoring my Mongo database to put users in a separate collection, and can't figure out how to save the result of this updated query so that plan names become user IDs:

```
db.plans.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "person",
        foreignField: "name",
        as: "person"
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "place",
        foreignField: "name",
        as: "place"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$person"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$place"
    }
},
{
    $set: {
        "person": "$person.id",
        "place": "$place.id",
    }
}
])
```

For example from this:

```
{
  "_id": "aeaab905-2d8b-4e26-9244-918956496c35",
  "id": "aeaab905-2d8b-4e26-9244-918956496c35",
  "person": "Alice",
  "place": "Bob"
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "_id": "aeaab905-2d8b-4e26-9244-918956496c35",
  "id": "aeaab905-2d8b-4e26-9244-918956496c35",
  "person": "a7609095-869e-4800-9fac-fefc373c37a5",
  "place": "2bd8f68d-721a-4106-bd7f-951236c3593d"
}
```

where db.users is:

```
[{
  "_id": "a7609095-869e-4800-9fac-fefc373c37a5",
  "id": "a7609095-869e-4800-9fac-fefc373c37a5",
  "name": "Alice"
},
{
  "_id": "2bd8f68d-721a-4106-bd7f-951236c3593d",
  "id": "2bd8f68d-721a-4106-bd7f-951236c3593d",
  "name": "Bob"
}]
```

Comment: Please provide sample documents and the requested response for them

Comment: You are after $out or $merge stage. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#comparison-with--merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex Blex [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74612901/update-mongo-collection-fields-with-values-from-other-collection?noredirect=1#comment131701802_74612901), [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-merge) worked:

```
db.plans.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "person",
        foreignField: "name",
        as: "person"
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "place",
        foreignField: "name",
        as: "place"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$person"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$place"
    }
},
{
    $set: {
        "person": "$person.id",
        "place": "$place.id",
    }
}, { $merge: { into: "plans", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
])
```